# How duplicated items can be deleted from dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
userid itemid
  1       1
  1       1
  1       3
  1       4
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
```

How can I drop duplicated items (not the index) to make the following `DataFrame`:

```
userid itemid
  1       1
  1       3
  1       4     
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
```

Can someone help me?

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2],
                   'itemid':[1,1,3,4, 1,2,3] })
```

Comment: df.drop_duplicates() ?

Comment: Please accept an answer if the problem is solved, otherwise people will  think it isn't and waste their time contributing solutions.

Answer (score 11):

The best way would be to use [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). If you have a larger DataFrame and only want those two columns checked, set subset equal to the combined columns you want checked.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

or

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['userid', 'itemid'])
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid reassignment, use (inplace = True)

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

This is same as

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop_duplicates()` of `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2],
                   'itemid':[1,1,3,4, 1,2,3] })
print(df)
print()
print(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Consider that drop won't change the df itself and just pass a new data frame which has dropped the specified row(s). If you want to change the `df` itself set `inside` parameter to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods are needed - 1) [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) 2) [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Below is a sample code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2],
                   'itemid':[1,1,3,4, 1,2,3] }
df.sort_values(by = ["userid", "itemid], ascending = True).drop_duplicates(subset = ["itemid"], keep="last")
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the following code:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['userid','itemid'])
```

Comment: This question is over one year old and already has several solutions, some of which are practically identical to yours...